# How to smooth a 3D matrix with a mask in matlab

Tags: matlab, filtering, smoothing

I need to smooth a 3D matrix `M`. The output of smoothing is `S`. The matlab code can be like this:

```
S = smooth3(M, 'box', 3);
```

The problem is only some parts in the matrix `M` should be considered during the smoothing. I have a mask `A` to identify the location of these parts. `A` has the same size as `M`, and the value of `1` means to consider this point and `0` means to ignore this point. How to do that?

For example, if I have `M` and `A` in the following:

```
M=zeros(7,7,7); M(2:6,2:6,2:6)=ones(5,5,5); M(4,4,4)=28;

A=zeros(7,7,7); A(2:6,2:6,2:6)=ones(5,5,5);
```

After the smoothing, I want to have the result like this:

```
S=zeros(7,7,7); S(2:6,2:6,2:6)=smooth3(M(2:6,2:6,2:6), 'box', 3);
```

Anyone knows how to do this kind of smoothing with mask in matlab? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can't you just smooth the entire array and then replace whatever's masked with the raw pixel values?

Comment: No. Because if the neighbors include ``A=0``, the smoothing result of the center point is not correct.

Comment: In that case you may need to write a smoothing routine that can handle NaNs.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
index=find(A==0);
M(index) = 0;

k=ones(3,3,3);
counts = convn(A,k,'same');
sums = convn(M,k,'same');

S= sums ./counts .* A;
```

I tested it. It seems ok.